# Can't connect to localhost after expo update

Tags: react-native, expo

I use expo and my iphone for create react-native application locally. A few months ago all was good. I used my local ip address for connecting to my local backend server. But after update expo started generate url as exp://r2-asw...exp.direct:80. Now I always get a connection error. I even can use my api via browser using my ip and port.

If I choose LAN instead Tunnel there is an infinity loader and get an error "There was a problem running the requested app. The request timed out"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in mac Brandmauer

Comment: @DejiJames you should allow expo in your brandmauer